# How to create collapse in a table for multiple columns and rows

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I don't understand how to create this table. Can you show me an example how to do it ?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: We have no idea what part of it you don't understand or what data source you are creating it from. This is not a tutorial service. You need to provide real code attempts if you need help